# Get width from the center of an element to the edge of viewport

Tags: jquery, width, element, viewport

Essentially the idea is to make `Element-B` and `Element-C` to cover the area *horizontally* starting from center of `Element-A` and ending at the edge of `viewport`.

So, I guess i want to get the distance value from the center of `Element-A` to the edge of `viewport`

**Additional notes**:

1. `Element-A` doesnt have static position or size.
2. `Element-B` and `Element-C` verticalposition or height is
   irrelevant.

[image]

**I was thinking something like this:**

1. Calculate width of `Element-A` and divide it by two ( Or just get half the width if theres a way. )
2. Get the distance from the edge of `Element-A` to the edge of
   `Viewport`
3. Add up these calculated values.

( Of course unless theres way to get that this width straight up )

I was trying to look for a way to do list item 2. but couldnt find a way to do that.. and that more or less screws up my idea..

I have no starting point except the basic set-up for the images http://jsfiddle.net/nsEth/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/nsEth/1/

```
var a = $('#Element-A'),
    b = $('#Element-B'),
    c = $('#Element-C'),
    aw;

$(window).resize(function() {
    b.width( aw = a.offset().left + a.width()/2 );
    c.width( $(window).width() - aw).css('left', aw);
}).resize();
```

Comment: That seems to do the job. I'm gonna be testing this out.. ( I didnt even think about window resize.. good call on that one. )